# Dark Fantasy Book of a Resentful Father

Tags: story-identification

- **Setting**: Dark Fantasy on Earth similar to our own
- **Important Plot Points:** The main villain is a father who resents his child as his wife died in childbirth. There is also a giant hooded figure.
- **Extra Notes:** I think there was a game based on the book to promote it. I remember learning of this story as a child. Don't know exactly when. After 2000.

Comment: Do you remember what the original language was it was published in? When it was published (when you read it might be a start)? Please refer to the [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/checklist-for-story-identification) for story IDs.

Comment: Pretty sure it was English

Comment: It was published in the nineteen sixties? Do you remember anything about the board game?

Comment: My previous comment was to illustrate that we're not mind readers, we don't know when you were a child - it might have been the 2000's it might equally have been the 1930's. Please [edit] your question to add some helpful details as per the checklist link in my first question.

Comment: Board game? Video game? ARG?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I seemed to be a video game, but my memory is so fuzzy I could have just imagined it.

Comment: Is the child male or female?

Comment: @Spencer I think male, but I tend to imagine protagonists as male always.